# Show a command prompt message(or, message at console) from windows application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a windows application, and i want to show some status messages at command prompt while executing the windows application, how can i do that `cmd.exe` can be run through windows code.but i don know how to show some message at command prompt or if there is any way to do something like `Console.WriteLine("Message")` through windows application.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666823/writing-to-the-command-line-in-a-windowed-app

Answer (score 1):

Console and windows applications don't mix well, for full explanation and the workarounds see this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/01/9259142.aspx