# .NET app running as either Windows Form or as Console Application

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I am looking to have one of my Windows Forms applications be run programmatically—from the command line. In preparation, I have separated the logic in its own class from the Form. Now I am stuck trying to get the application to switch back and forth based on the presence of command line arguments.

Here is the code for the main class:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length > 1) // gets passed its path, by default
        {
            CommandLineWork(args);
            return;
        }         

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private static void CommandLineWork(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It works!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

where `Form1` is my form and the `It works!` string is just a placeholder for the actual logic.

Right now, when running this from within Visual Studio (with command line arguments), the phrase `It works!` is printed to the Output. However, when running the /bin/Debug/Program.exe file (or /Release for that matter) the application crashes.

Am I going all this the right way? Would it make more sense (i.e. take less developer time) to have my logic class be a DLL that gets loaded by two separate applications? Or is there something entirely different that I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exception are you getting when the app crashes?  Also, I assume it should be args.Length >= 1 (or > 0) instead of > 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show a console output/window in a forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll need to P/Invoke AllocConsole() if you detect a command line argument.  Check my answer in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvb/thread/875952fc-cd2c-4e74-9cf2-d38910bde613) for the required code.  A C# sample is further down the page.  Repeated here because I don't trust that crummy forum site:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
  static class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      if (args.Length > 0) {
        // Command line given, display console
        AllocConsole();
        ConsoleMain(args);
      }
      else {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
      }
    }

    private static void ConsoleMain(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Command line = {0}", Environment.CommandLine);
      for (int ix = 0; ix < args.Length; ++ix)
        Console.WriteLine("Argument{0} = {1}", ix + 1, args[ix]);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `FreeConsole`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786840/c-is-it-possible-to-have-a-single-application-behave-as-console-or-windows-appl/1787008#1787008

Comment: Why not just make it a console app in the first place and then reference the Forms assembly for the windowing?

Comment: @Chris: get a console only on demand, not always.  FreeConsole is a *nasty* flash.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be better to make two frontend .exes (one for the command line and one for windowing).

The main reason is that you have to specify the output type for your project (either command line or Windows application and you can't select both.

So you would have to always use the Windows application output type (which comes at an overhead for the Windows messaging system and doesn't give you "real" command line).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it makes a difference but instead of

```
static void Main()
{
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

you can instead put

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
```

Comment: As this is no solution to the problem at hand this should be a comment not a answer?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project properties

On the <kbd>Application</kbd> tab you should see a dropdown list named <kbd>Output Type</kbd>. Change this to <kbd>Console Application</kbd>.

There, you have both a window and a console. Now your code with command argument should work.