# How Console.write() in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, console, console-application

I am making a C# windows form application. I want Console.write() in my form application. I read lot of stuff. But did not work. Can you give me a clean code to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    Console.WriteLine("This is from the main program");
}
```

This is not working for me.

Comment: Look here (both question and answer(s)): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743387/behavior-in-winform-console-hybrid-application

Comment: Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613880/difference-between-console-and-winforms-applications-when-running-from-cmd

Comment: What do you need? Winform app to have console window also? and you want to write in console?

Comment: @elgonzo I edited the question. Unfortunately that thing is not working :(

Comment: @user3218743 Refer my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're complicating things. You can get what you want just by changing project properties.

- Create windows application project, show new form etc
- Go to project properties->Application-> Change output type-> Console Application.

and you're done. you get a console for free in windows application.

Comment: Thanks. But I need Windows form capabilities too. Like buttons and text-boxes. Console to show the dataflow.

Comment: @user3218743 Did you try this? You can get all what you need. You can just convert your existing winforms application to console app type. That's it. Form will be shown as usual with a console window also,

Answer (score 3):

Bringing up the console on Form Application is difficult
If you're looking for a way to show an output, you can use

```
MessageBox.Show("TEXT HERE");
```

And that will bring up a dialog box with the text you used.

Hopefully that helps you out :)

Comment: Thanks. But this is not helping me because I have to show a large data flow.

Answer (score 1):

You might enjoy `using System.Diagnostics` for its `Debug.WriteLine()` which works great in windows forms apps and will not accidentally spill over into Release configurations.

According to your edit, and @elgonzo's suggestion, you've now prepared the app to attach to a console but ... are you *running* the app from cmd.exe?  If you do, the calls to `Console.Write` should end up there.

Comment: I am currently using this. But need to print it on console. :)